# WM_CLOSE message does not seem to close chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, winapi, pinvoke

I am trying to close chrome from my application.

I am using the following method:

```
public class CloseChrome 
{

    static int WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;
    static int WM_QUIT = 0x0012;



    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);



    static public void closeCrome()
    {

        var process = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (var item in process)
        {
            if (item.ProcessName.Contains("chrome"))
            {
                //item.Kill();

                int ret = SendMessage(item.Handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
                Console.WriteLine("Chrome Reply: " + a);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Using the kill method kills the chrome process, but when I send the WM_CLOSE message nothing happens even though the return value is 0 from sendMessage. Am I doing something wrong is chrome just ignoring my request?

Comment: Have you tried just calling `item.CloseMainWindow();`  It's the same as sending WM_CLOSE.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work, but why is WM_CLOSE not working

Comment: I don't know.  I can only speculate that maybe `item.Handle` is not the handle to the main window.  You could also try using PostMessage rather than SendMessage, but I don't know if that will work either.

Comment: Process.Handle will be the process handle, not the window handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process.Handle will be the HANDLE of the process, not the HWND of the main window. In fact a process can own many windows, so the concept of a main window doesn't really apply.

What you need to do is call the (csharp equivalent of) `EnumWindows` and then call `GetWindowProcessThreadId` to test each HWND to see if it belongs to your target process.

The more usual alternative is to examine a target window with Spy++ to see if the class name is pretty unique, and if it is, you can use `FindWindow`.